# Sql Query inside while loop making my application very slow

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Sql Query inside while loop making my application very slow.

```
<ul>    
<?php 
$sql1 = "SELECT cat_id,cat_name FROM all_services where uni_id='$uni_id'";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
while($display_class = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query))
{
$class_id = $display_class['cat_id'];
?>
<li>
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
<label>
<input  id="1" data-id="1" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo "$class_id";   ?>"/><?php echo $display_class['cat_name']; ?>
</label>
<ul>
<?php  $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT roll_no,st_name,st_mobile,st_dob FROM student_info where school_uni_id='$uni_id' and st_class='$class_id' order by roll_no + 0 ASC, st_name ASC"); 
while($display_stu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2))
{
?>
<li>
<label>
<input class="treenode" id="xnode-0-1-1" data-id="custom-0-1-1" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $display_stu['st_mobile']; ?>,<?php echo $display_stu['st_dob']; ?>" /><?php echo $display_stu['roll_no']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $display_stu['st_name']; ?>
</label>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Both sql query is linked to each other, I need `$class_id` from first query `$sql1` to put in second query i.e `$sql2`.

While loop inside while loop making it very slow.

It works fine if query result is upto 1000rows but above 2000rows application become very slow. How to make my application fast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the N+1 SELECT query issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-select-query-issue)

Answer (score 0):

//You didn't inform about MySQL database size & server configuration but following steps will faster your while loop

// Please add MySQL index `uni_id` at `all_services` table.

// I have make some changes at $sql2

$sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT roll_no,st_name,st_mobile,st_dob FROM student_info where school_uni_id='$uni_id' order by roll_no ASC");

//Please add MySQL index `school_uni_id` & `roll_no`  at `student_info` table.

Answer (score -1):

You need to paginate your page using query parameters.
Your while is useless: you can directly fetch your result is the same way.